# Ellaboration of combvec command

Tags: matlab, matrix, iteration

When i use combvec command for matlab, for large number of iterations (say rows=120, colums=20) it tries to save it as a matrix, and due to that every it says, *out of memory*.

So is there a way by which i can get the result of each iteration individually and check for the required conditions, instead of saving all of them it would save the memory.